# Product of its Prime Factors

Tags: prime-numbers

Given that $4095 = 8^4 - 1$ write $4095$ as a product of its prime factors.

I know how I could separate $4095$ into prime factors however I'm not sure how I could use $8^4 - 1$ to help me.

I could perhaps move the $1$ over to get $4096$ and then work from there...

Comment: $x^4-1=(x^2)^2-1^2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$8^4-1=(8^2+1)(8^2-1)=5\cdot13\cdot7\cdot3^2$$

Comment: I understand that you have worked out the difference of two squares however how did you conclude with $5, 13, 7, 3^2$

Comment: @PerfectNutter These are small numbers: $\;8^2+1=65=5\cdot13\;,\;\;8^2-1=63=7\cdot9=7\cdot3^2\;$, etc.

Answer (score 4):

To be more systematic:
\begin{align*}
x^{12}-1 &= (x^6-1)(x^6+1)\\
&=(x^3-1)(x^3+1)(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)\\
&=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)
\end{align*}
(As a polynomial it could be factored further).

Now set $x=2$.  You get
$$4095=1\cdot 7\cdot3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot13=3^2\cdot5\cdot 7\cdot 13.$$